# Multiplying Arrays of Uneven Length based on criteria and Summing the result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have two tables in my spreadsheet, a Name Table:

[image: Name Table]

and a Category Table:

[image: Category Table]

From the above two, how do I create a formula that lets me calculate cost by category in a single cell as shown below:

[image: Required Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Output" Category Column, `H3` formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E$3:E$8,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF(H$2:H2,E$3:E$8),0),0)),"")
```

and,

In "Output" Cost Column, `I3` formula copied down :

```
=IF(H3="","",SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(F$3:F$8,D$3:D$8,A$3:A$4,E$3:E$8,H3)*B$3:B$4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get distinct category list you can use `INDEX` + `AGGREGATE` functions:

```
=INDEX(Category[Category],AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(COUNTIF($A$11:A11,Category[Category])=0))*ROW(Category[Category])-1,1))
```

after that you can calculate cost with `SUMPRODUCT` function entered as array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(([@Category]=Category[Category])*(Category[Name]=TRANSPOSE(Name[Name]))*(Category[Percent]*TRANSPOSE(Name[Cost])))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]